# What do $a_0$ ,$a_m$ and $b_m$ terms mean in the Fourier series formula?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

We know that a Fourier series for signal $x(t)$ is given as

$$\frac {a_0} 2 + \sum \limits _{m=1} ^\infty (a_m \cos \frac {2 \pi m t} T + b_m \sin \frac {2 \pi m t} T)$$

So my question is

> what do $a_0$,$a_m$ and  $b_m$ terms mean in the Fourier series formula?
>
> How are they important in Fourier analysis and synthesis ?

Comment: It means how heavy this term contributes to the entire solution.

Comment: @MonkeyKing yes sir you are right

Comment: You can think of the Fourier modes in terms of sound instead of sight. You can reconstruct any sound over $[0,T]$ by combining a fundamental tone and all of its harmonics if you get the amplitudes right. Once you get the amplitudes of the harmonics right, the sound will repeat itself over and over with periodicity $T$ seconds. The term 'harmonic analysis' is related.

Comment: @T.A.E. sir but what is $a_0$ ?

Comment: @pandu : an offset.

Comment: @T.A.E. because suppose a signal $x(t)$ is made of only 3 sinusoidal functions,2 are sine functions and 1 cosine functions .then where is the $a_0$ i.e. dc signal term comes ?

Comment: @T.A.E. sorry sir but i don't understand what you want to say. Could you explain about it little bit more ?

Comment: It's an offset, a center point about which everything vibrates.

Comment: @T.A.E. 
suppose these 3 signals are $2∗sin(wt)$ ,$sin(4∗wt)$ and $cos(wt)$. Then, will you write the equation for $x(t)$ using Fourier series formula including the $a_0$ ?

Comment: The Fourier series can represent the signals over a period of the Fourier series. After that, the signal being represented will not agree, unless the signal being represented has the same periodicity. You can represent a voice snippet over an interval $[0,T]$ and the Fourier series signal will repeat itself periodically after that.

Answer (score 3):

The $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are respectfully the real and imaginary parts of the complex number in the $i$th position of the vector $F_nx$, where $F_n \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is the Fourier transform matrix.  For example, $F_4$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & \omega & \omega^2 & \omega^3 \\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega^4 & \omega^6 \\
1 & \omega^3 & \omega^6 & \omega^9
\end{bmatrix}$$
and with $n=4$, $\omega=\exp(\frac{-2\pi i}{n})=\exp(\frac{-\pi i}{2})$.

Now if $$x=\begin{bmatrix} 
1  \\ 
0  \\
1  \\
2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $F_4x$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
4  \\ 
1+i  \\
0  \\
-2i 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So that $a_0=4, b_0=0, a_1=1, b_1=1, a_2=b_2=0, a_3=0$ and $b_3=-2$

Comment: The original question concerned the real Fourier transform, and its quite likely that its really about explaining sigma notation. Your answer uses complex numbers, matrices, and a quite abstract view of the Fourier Transform. Looking at the question, I very much doubt that the original questioner has the slightest idea of what you are talking about. Anybody who could understand your answer would never ask the original question.

Comment: This only covers the case when the function to develop is a trigonometric polynomial. In general one has an infinite number of modes.

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea what this answer has to do with the Fourier transform. Is it maybe related to the *discrete* Fourier transform?

Answer (score 3):

One is studying periodic functions with given period $T>0$. Among these there are very special ones, the *pure harmonic functions*
$$t\mapsto\cos{2\pi k t\over T}\quad(k\geq0),\qquad t\mapsto\sin{2\pi k t\over T}\quad(k\geq1)\ .$$
These functions have very useful algebraic and analytic properties, and we understand them very well.

It is a miracle that **any** reasonable $T$-periodic function $f$ can be written as a linear combination (or *superposition*) of these special functions:
$$f(t)={a_0\over2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(a_k\cos{2\pi k t\over T}+b_k\sin{2\pi k t\over T}\right)\ .$$
The "physical" interpretation of the coefficient pair $(a_k,b_k)$ is the following: It tells you with which intensity and phase the pure harmonic $t\mapsto\cos{2\pi k t\over T}$ is present in $f$. An example: If $a_7=10$, $b_7=3$, and all other $a_k$, $b_k$ are $\ll1$, and altogether they converge to $0$ when $k\to\infty$ then the function $f$ is not far away from a pure harmonic with $7$ peaks per period.

Concerning light spectra: The frequency $\omega$ of light waves can have any real value in a  certain interval $[\omega_\min,\omega_\max]$. The Fourier representation of an arbitrary (steady) light signal would then look as follows:
$$f(t)=\int_{\omega_\min}^{\omega_\max} \bigl(a(\omega)\cos(\omega t)+b(\omega)\sin(\omega t)\bigr)\>d\omega\ .$$
A physical device that can separate the various frequencies, like a prism or a spectrometer, will show bright bands or dots along an $\omega$-scale at places where the corresponding values $a(\omega)$, $b(\omega)$ are large. From white light you get a broad band (which even shows the colors, but this is secondary), since all frequencies are equally present; whereas from a methane flame you only get dots at places characteristic for methane.

Comment: sir,thank you very much for your answer but what is $a_0$ specifically ?

Comment: because suppose a signal $x(t)$ is made of only 3 sinusoidal functions,2 are sine functions and 1 cosine functions .then where is the $a_0$ i.e. dc signal term comes ?

Comment: The constant term ${a_0\over2}$ in the Fourier expansion of a periodic function $f$ is the average of $f$ over one period.

Comment: suppose these 3 signals are $2*sin(wt)$ ,$sin(4*wt)$ and $cos(wt)$. Then, will you write the equation for $x(t)$ using Fourier series formula including the $a_0$ term?

Comment: If  $\omega$ is a  constant then the Fourier expansion of your combined signal is just $$x(t)=2\sin(\omega t)+\sin(4\omega t)+\cos(\omega t)\ .$$ The whole machinery is only needed when the signal is just an old periodic function, and is not already given as a superposition of specific harmonics.